# vue-components-autodetect-webpack subdirectory appends no slashes

Tags: webpack, import, vue.js, vue-component

I have been using the package which is stated in the title, which is: 
https://github.com/tecbeast42/vue-components-autodetect-webpack

But I have encountered one problem which prevents me from running my project,
This is my current webpack configuration:

```
    {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'vue-components-autodetect-webpack',
                    options: {
                        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages'),
                        separator: '-',
                        injectComment: /(\/\/\s*{{\s*inject-vue-components\s*}}\n?)/ig,
                        exclude: ['page'],
                        type: 'import',
                        appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

And the problem is that, 'pages' has sub directories, for this example it has "hello" with "Test.vue" as component in it. As shown here: 

  `|-- frontend
          | -- pages
              | -- hello
                  | -- Test.vue
          | -- index.ts`

Upon loading it in my console then says: 
ERROR in ./frontend/components.ts 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pageshelloTest.vue' in '*\frontend'
 @ ./frontend/index.ts 17:0-39 18:23-31
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./frontend/index.ts

It doesn't append any slashes from the sub directories!

And the comment to place all the imports is located inside index.ts 
I dont know if im missing something or if this is an issue, please help!

Comment: Can you pass a glob pattern to `path` like `path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/**/*.vue)`? Also, side note, but it's recommended to use `process.cwd()` as opposed to `__dirname` for better environment agnostic support

Comment: That threw another error, being:

ERROR in ./frontend/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir      '*\frontend\pages\**\*.vue'


So to answer your question, I don't think that's supported!

Comment: Yep. that's not supported. However, looking at the code it's using `fs` to recursively read the path. [I've highlighted the line in question here](https://github.com/tecbeast42/vue-components-autodetect-webpack/blob/master/index.js#L37)

Comment: Ah, yess, I see. I've required process and used it as such: 
`path:  path.resolve(process.cwd(), './frontend/pages/')`, but still, to no avail.

Comment: I've found out what the problem is! This package generates a url but this url uses backslashes, which for some reason are ommited by my webserver to, well, nothing. Using a replace on the 'component.path' to replace the backslashes to forwardslashes fixes the issue, question is, is there a normal solution to this?